# Keyboard sometimes randomly gets scrambled in Blender

Tags: interface

I began using Blender this year and have loved it and modelled a cool stink bug. However, I have a more annoying kind of bug..

Sometimes the keyboard gets scrambled such that if I press any key over and over again it will type a different random key in Blender.

For example, if I press "ssss" Blender will type "k*,#" and if I press ##kk blender will type "p_o[".

This gets really annoying when using shortcuts and it often takes me awhile each time to figure out what is happening. The currently solution I have is to save blender each time it happens, close the program and open it again.

Is there another way to fix this issue and why is it happening?

This issue is happening **only in Blender** (if I use another application the keyboard works fine).

Cheers

Joel

Comment: Hello and welcome. Do you have multiple keyboard layouts to which you can switch to? or is it only `EN`? Maybe it is a keyboard hardware issue?

Comment: This happens after some time using the application? After re-opening Blender, does it work for a while?

Comment: Harry, I am not aware of having any other keyboard layouts. 

Robin, it will happen awhile after opening Blender. Most of the time it works fine but sometimes it has this glitch and I'm not aware of pressing anything to cause it each time it happens. When I have the problem I can type in other applications and the keyboard works fine but when I come back to Blender it does not work properly until I close and reopen Blender. Sometimes just saving Blender fixes the problem. Blender will then work fine again for some time and then the glitch will come back.